# Can I enable GZIP on Godaddy?

Tags: htaccess, godaddy, gzip

One of my sites lives on GoDaddy's bottom-of-the-line cheap hosting, I have the correct code in my `.htaccess` file, but it's not compressing because mod_deflate is not loaded.

How do I enable that?

The best I've found is an article on GoDaddy which suggests I use PHP to zip everything (which is going to be more work than just changing hosting companies):

> Add the following code to the very top of your Web pages above the DOCTYPE:
>
> `if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
>       b_start("ob_gzhandler");
>   else ob_start();`

Comment: Just to add some results, the shared hosting does not seem to be able to take a lot of traffic.  I host my wordpress blog there to keep my real sites safe, and under a few thousand visitors an hour the server is accessible maybe 50-70% of the time.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but it shows up early on google so I thought I would answer it.  You can now enable gzip on GoDaddy by adding the following to the .htaccess in your root directory.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

[Source - GoDaddy Support](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6946/enabling-mod_deflate-with-your-hosting-account?locale=en)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a shared hosting account there is no way to add mod_deflate since it requires making changes to Apache which you are not allowed to. So your options are to either switch hosts or use the PHP solution godaddy suggests.